# Do contractualist deontological theories face any difficulties with the trolley problem?

Tags: ethics, deontology, moral-agency

I was wondering what problems contractualist approaches face with the trolley problem. Also, what other problems may contractualism have with aggregation as a whole?

Comment: The template for, "Theory of morality X runs into a trolly problem," is, "X prescribes something different from/contrary to our intuitions about some trolly problem." So if contractualism decidably prescribes some response or other to a determinate trolly problem, and this response is counterintuitive, and if you accept "being counterintuitive" as conclusive enough, and if you assume your intuitions can't or at least won't change, and...

Comment: Contractualism [rejects the double effect doctrine](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contractualism/#IrrIntent) which is intuitively popular for the trolley problem, but it is unclear if this is a flaw or a benefit. On moral aggregation see [Fried's Can Contractualism Save Us from Aggregation?](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10892-011-9113-3) He argues that unintended harm to others "*can be regulated only by principles that accept the necessity of making precisely the sorts of interpersonal trade-offs that contractualism is foundationally committed to reject*".